# How to use RavenDB queries in Data Layer or Classes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ravendb, n-tier-architecture

I have setup RavenDB embedded in my MVC application. I follower all the tutorials to make the `RavenController` and I can query the `Session` in the controller.

Now I would really like to break away from mixing data in the controller and create a Data layer so that I can do some Business logic which will help me create complex View Models.

How do I query the `Session` in a plain class file? I can't seem to find any info on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependency Injection is great for this. You move aside the creation of the necessary services and let the container manage the lifecycle of the components, including scoping IDocumentSession to one instance per HTTP request.

As an example, using [Autofac](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac) (you'd need both the [Autofac](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac) and [Autofac.Mvc5](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Mvc5/) packages) you could have a class in your App_Start folder like this, and then call `AutofacConfig.Configure()` from your Global.asax:

```
public static class AutofacConfig
{
    public static IContainer Container { get; private set; }

    public static void Configure()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        var thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        // Register our controllers with the container
        builder.RegisterControllers(thisAssembly).PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.PreserveSetValues);

        // Provide injections of the HTTP abstractions (HttpContextBase, etc.)
        builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());

        // Create and register the Raven IDocumentStore
        builder.Register(c =>
        {
            var store = new DocumentStore {ConnectionStringName = "RavenDB"};
            store.Initialize();

            Raven.Client.Indexes.IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof (MvcApplication).Assembly, store);

            return store;
        })
            .As<IDocumentStore>()
            .SingleInstance();

        // Provide injection of Raven IDocumentSession
        builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<IDocumentStore>().OpenSession())
            .InstancePerRequest();

        Container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(Container));
    }
}
```

Then, when you need an `IDocumentSession` some place outside of a controller:

```
// Business logic, or other class that injection is not provided for.
var session = AutofacConfig.Container.Resolve<IDocumentSession>();
```

Also include autofac otherwise you will get an error saying "does not contain definition `Resolve` ..."

```
using Autofac;
```

You can do similar things with most other DI container libraries; the API is just slightly different.

Comment: Thank you. I have not used DI before but I suppose its time to learn this as it seems to be used in allot of projects now.

Comment: This is defiantly the correct answer! And I like the way you demonstrated how to Inject the DB Context, similar to LINQ2SQL or Entity. Will use this and AutoFac but, I will also check out the other DI - [There is also this tutotrial that is worth a read if somebody else is trying to work out how to do it](http://lvasquez.github.io/2014/07/20/RavenDB-ASP-MVC-DI/)

Comment: This is not proper Dependency injection, but rather the pattern "Service Locator", often considered an anti-pattern. Read more about why here: http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/how-not-to-do-dependency-injection-the-static-or-singleton-container

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext.Current.Session` holds current session, but you should definitely not use it in business logic layer. Business logic layer should not be aware of `HttpContext`.

Basic solution to this problem would be to create interface:

```
public interface ISession 
{
    int SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

and implementation

```
public class HttpContextBasedSession : ISession 
{
    public int SomeValue
    {
        get
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["SomeValue"]);
        }

        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["SomeValue"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Bind it with dependency injection framework.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of that - But I think the Session is ambiguous here, sorry, as the RavenDB is the DocuemntStore Session.(Unless I am incorrect) Does that mean I have to create a helper class that opens the DocuemtStore and similar to LINQ2SQL does with DBML and then use that to query the DB in the Business?

Comment: @ppumkin: That is a long story. You should probably get some knowledge about unit of work and repository patterns.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I got allot of reading ahead of me to work this out then.